# How do I undor/redo edits in Windows 10 CMD?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe, text-editing, undo

I see that CMD got a some changes for 10. Including ctrl+C/V.
And for some reason they ruined drag&drop which now ovewrites text instead of inserting it...

But so far I didn't find undo which is sorely needed with CMD that pastes stuff on right click (wacky...), also pressing tab accidentally deletes stuff from the command  line unrecoverably. The expected  ctrl+z shortcut doesn't work. Nor does it appear in the context menu

Comment: There is no undo support in the command prompt, but you can recall previously executed commands using the up and down arrow, or press F7 to get those in a popup list.

Comment: That said, Powershell, which can do command prompt commands, DOES support CTRL-Z and CTRL-Y